# Changing primefaces accordion icons

Tags: css, jsf, icons, primefaces, accordion

Is there any way to change the icons in the accordion panel of the primefaces?

I want to change the   right and down arrow to plus([+]) and minus([-]) sign .

Can anyone explain how to do it??

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could throw in some custom CSS which changes the background position of the default icons to plus and minus:

```css
.ui-accordion .ui-icon.ui-icon-triangle-1-e {
    background-position: -16px -128px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-icon.ui-icon-triangle-1-s {
    background-position: -48px -128px;
}
```

With the current PrimeFaces 3.2 release, there doesn't seem to be a more clean way to explicitly specify the `.ui-icon-plus` and `.ui-icon-minus` on the `<p:accordionPanel>` component instead. You may want to post an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/) for this.

Comment: Isn't the icon source mentioned somewhere for the accordion so that we can change the source to point it to plus and minus ??

Comment: Look in the default CSS for it. It points to a CSS sprite. All you can do is changing the background poisition, exactly as explained in my answer. Just add those CSS declarations to your custom CSS file. Add if necessary a more specific class so that it get applied on specific accordion components only.

Answer (score 0):

you can using the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#[accordion-id] h3 span.ui-icon").removeClass( "ui-icon-triangle-1-e" ).addClass( "ui-icon-plus" )
});
```

don't forget to replace the [accordion-id] with correct ***Accordion Id***

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using this CSS code:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a .ui-accordion-toggle-icon::before { 
    content:'\e90d';
}
```